# c++ check if file is empty

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I got a project in C++ which I need to edit. This is a declaration of variable:

```
// Attachment
    OFSTRUCT ofstruct;
    HFILE hFile = OpenFile( mmsHandle->hTemporalFileName , &ofstruct , OF_READ );
    DWORD hFileSize = GetFileSize( (HANDLE) hFile , NULL );
    LPSTR hFileBuffer = (LPSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, sizeof(CHAR) * hFileSize );
    DWORD hFileSizeReaded = 0;
    ReadFile( (HANDLE) hFile , hFileBuffer, hFileSize, &hFileSizeReaded, NULL );
    CloseHandle( (HANDLE) hFile );
```

I need to check if the file is attached (I suppose I need to check if hFile has any value), but don't know how. I tried with `hFile == NULL` but this doesn't do the job.

Thanks,
Ile

Answer (score 6):

Compare hFile with HFILE_ERROR (not with NULL!). Also, you should change OpenFile to CreateFile and call it properly, OpenFile has long been deprecated. In fact MSDN clearly states:

> OpenFile Function
>
> Only use this function with 16-bit
> versions of Windows. For newer
> applications, use the CreateFile
> function.

When you make this change, you will get a HANDLE back, which you should compare with INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Update: Correct way to get a file's size:

```
LARGE_INTEGER fileSize={0};

// You may want to use a security descriptor, tweak file sharing, etc...
// But this is a boiler plate file open
HANDLE hFile=CreateFile(mmsHandle->hTemporalFileName,GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,
                        OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

if (hFile!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && GetFileSizeEx(hFile,&fileSize) && 
    fileSize.QuadPart!=0)
{
  // The file has size
}
else
{
  // The file is missing or size==0 (or an error occurred getting its size)
}

// Do whatever else and don't forget to close the file handle when done!
if (hFile!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Comment: is there any example of using HFILE_ERROR? Thx

Comment: hmm, it looks like I never get error... Maybe it's because program automatically creates an empty file. Do you know maybe how to check what is the 'DWORD hFileSize' value and compare it with something?

Comment: Are you trying to test if the file exists or get its length? I can't quite understand your goal.

Comment: The thing is that the program automatically creates new file (at least I think so - application is pretty big and as far as I figured out it works this way) and then user is suppose to do some actions on that file and that's where I need to make validation. I need to check if the file is empty or it has some content.

Answer (score 1):

Before you open the file you can try this:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(filename, &wfd);
if (h != INVALID_FILE_HANDLE)
{
    // file exists
    if (wfd.nFileSizeHigh != 0 || wfd.nFileSizeLow != 0)
    {
        // file is not empty
    }
    FindClose(h)
}
```

Comment: This may not work, because often times, as a file is being written to it's metadata including its file length is not updated. That is why you see working files with zero size when you look in their directory. You have to "touch" the file (e.g., by reading it) to update its file length.

Comment: From MSDN: Note: In rare cases, file information on NTFS file systems may not be current at the time you call this function (FindFirstFile). To be assured of getting the current file information, call the GetFileInformationByHandle function. @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Michael, thanks for those caveats. If I understand correctly there's a possibility that a file will show empty when it's not, but not the other way around?

Comment: It may show empty or with fewer bytes than are actually there.